# Unable to create Shortcut for creating new note in Evernote

Tags: iphone, shortcuts-app, evernote

I am trying to create a Shortcut that will create a new note in Evernote. It should ask me to enter some text for the note.

In my Shortcut app, I create a new Shortcut and for Content I select Shortcut Input. But when I run this Shortcut, it simply creates an empty note in Evernote and does not ask me for any input text. Below is the screenshot.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the '[Ask for Input](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/shortcuts/apd68b5c9161/ios)' action before the Evernote app.
This way, you will be asked to enter text that can then be used in Evernote (with the 'Provided Input' variable).

Note that the 'Shortcut Input' variable takes the content from where you called it (for example a website in the share sheet).